# How to correctly wait for async function to finish before executing another function in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm writing a react app with an api written in python with FastAPI.

This is what my code looks like:

```
export default function Menu() {
    const [abstracts, setAbstracts] = useState<Array<string>>([])
    const [abstractsId, setId] = useState<string>("")
    const [entities, setEntities] = useState<any>([])
    const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState<boolean>(false)
    const location = useLocation()
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const fetchAbstracts = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/data")
        const data = await response.json()
        setAbstracts(data.abstracts)
        setEntities(data.entities)
        setId(data._id)
    }

    const saveAbstracts = async () => {
        await fetchAbstracts()
        entities[location.state.id] = location.state.entities
        await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/data/${abstractsId}`, {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({ 'entities': entities })
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (location.state.path == "/annotate") {
            saveAbstracts()
        } else {
            fetchAbstracts()
        }

    }, [])
```

My issue is when I try to send the data to the api, using the saveAbstracts function `abstractsId` is empty, so I get the following error:

[image]

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing about `setState` in ractjs is that they are asynchronous. So, when you call the `await fetchAbstracts()` inside of `saveAbstracts` it fetches the data and then calls `setAbstracts` and the component updates, but the context of that function did not change, so the new `abstracts` will not be there to use. A very simple solution to this could be just returning the data from the `fetchAbstracts` function as such:

```
const fetchAbstracts = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/data")
    const data = await response.json()
    setAbstracts(data.abstracts)
    setEntities(data.entities)
    setId(data._id)
    return data;
}

const saveAbstracts = async () => {
    const data = await fetchAbstracts()
....
```